# Need help finding the Horizontal Tangent of an Implicit Equation

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

I am given the equation: $(x^3) + (y^3) - (72xy) = 0  $.
I found the derivative to be: $(-3x^2 + 72y)/(3y^2 - 72 x)  $
I know that the numerator of the derivative must be set to $0$ in order to proceed but I am unsure of what to do after that.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: $$\implies 24y= x^2$$  Replace this in the given equation

Comment: Thank you so much I understand it now! @labbhattacharjee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with $$y=y(x)$$ we get $$3x^2+3y^2y'-72y-72xy'=0$$ from here we get $$y'(3y^2-72x)=72y-3x^2$$

Answer (score 0):

Your plan is correct: Taking the curve 
$$
x^3+y^3-72xy=0
$$
and differentiating implicitly we get

$$
\frac{x^2-24y}{24x-y^2}=\frac{dy}{dx}
$$
which is only zero when $\frac{x^2}{24}=y$. It remains to see when this parabola intersects the original curve, which you can find by plugging in the equation for y into the equation for the original curve and solving the system.